# How to execute only some functions from other python modules?

Tags: python, import, module

[Problem] I want to execute only some functions from other python modules

[Input]
module 1, module 2

module 1 includes:

1. function that is called ( def a)
2. function that is called ( def b)

[module 2] includes:

```
from module1 import b
```

Current: function a and function b are executed.
Desired: ONLY function b should be executed.

If you have any ideas please share.

Comment: Functions are executed only if they are called. Your question is not clear enough. Add your code or a section of the code.

Comment: You might want to provide a more concrete example.

Comment: module1.py; def a(): print "abc" a(); def b(); print "zzz" b(); module2.py; from module1 import b. This will print : abc and zzz.

Comment: If you don't want your functions called when the module is imported, don't call them in the module.

Comment: @ kindall. yes, I see your point. In the same time in the current design I need to call them. Therefore if there is no other way then I will try to split module1.py into module 1a and module 1b and/or refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you import a module that has code outside a class/function, that code will run.
If your module calls a function outside a definition, it runs. Consider not calling the function in the module file.

Comment: @ pydude. yes I have noticed that if a function is not called in the module from were it's imported than it won't get executed.